# Play 2.0 on MK 802+

Tags: scala, arm, playframework-2.0, ubuntu-12.04

I have got a mini pc (MK 802) with Allwinner A10. I want to use this mini pc as a home server for hosting my play 2.0 Scala applications. Currently I have Lubuntu 12.04 on this mini pc. How I can install Play Framework on this device?

Answer (score 1):

Your probably going to have to download the source code of OpenJDK and build it on your MK 802. If your lucky you might already have the package (icedtea) installed. This doc might help: http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk6-dev/2009-April/000455.html

As for Play 2.0 and Scala you just download and put them in a directory and set some ENV variables.

Comment: I found openjdk-6-jdk in the repository. I will try this with play-2.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running a bunch of stuff on Ubuntu 12.04. I normally just install openjdk-7-jre and then pull down the sbt jar. Since the build system in Play 2.0 is based on sbt, it'll pull in play and scala as needed. All I have to do is setup java and sbt, and then do an 'sbt run' from the project directory and everything gets pulled down on demand.

Comment: I'm not able to start an example. I get a lot of errors like this: error: error while loading SerialVersionUID, class file 'play-2.0.3/framework/sbt/boot/scala-2.9.1/lib/scala-library.jar(scala/SerialVersionUID.class)' is broken
(error reading Scala signature of play-2.0.3/framework/sbt/boot/scala-2.9.1/lib/scala-library.jar
[error] java.lang.NullPointerException: 
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.

Comment: I just checked this again using the helloworld sample from Play 2.0.3. I have openjdk-7-jdk installed, and I used the deb from http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html#deb to install the Typesafe repo and then used apt-get to install sbt. For some reason the plugins for the default project definition aren't resolving, so I had to start the example with 'sbt -Dplay.version=2.0.3 run'. But once I explicitly put in the version it started up fine. I haven't seen the errors you seem to be getting.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try this way tommorow. Which Linux is in your MK802?

Comment: I don't have this on an MK802, just in a VM running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: do you run a x86-version of Ubuntu 12.04 or a special arm-version?

Comment: If I run a sample "forms", I get following error: "Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-1] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[play]"